# getting last committed code from git

Tags: git, commit, reset, pull

I `commit`ted some code and `push`ed it to my `github` account.Then ,I modified the code on my machine.I did not `add it to the index` or `commit` it.Now I want to remove all those modifications and make the code on my machine the same as what I committed earlier..I am somewhat confused by the various commands -like `pull,reset head` etc.. (My github account contains only my code ..nobody else pushes to it)

Can someone please advise me what to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to throw away uncommitted work is:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```